# how to find a sum of an object in an array

Tags: javascript

I've got this array of objects and I would like to calculate how much time  the students are spending on particular subjects according to some conditions.

I've got this code to identify subjects:
But I am struggling to find the sum of minutes of those particular subjects.

```
$scope.total = 0;
$scope.found = [];

angular.forEach($scope.all, function(value, index) {
    angular.forEach(value.time, function (item, index) {

        $scope.total += value.time[index].minutes;

         if (item.subject === "english" || item.subject === "maths"    
         && $scope.total === 150) {
             $scope.found.push(value); 
         }
    });
});
```

```
"students": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Natalie",
        "gender": "female",
        "time": [
            {
                "subject": "geography",
                "minutes": 100
            },{
                "subject": "english",
                "minutes": 20
            },{
                "subject": "maths",
                "minutes": 760
            }
        ]
    },{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "John",
        "gender": "male",
        "time": [
            {
                "subject": "spanish",
                "minutes": 450
            },{
                "subject": "maths",
                "minutes": 900
            },{
                "subject": "geography",
                "minutes": 200
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You didn't post valid JavaScript. If I try to run the code you posted, it will throw an error.

Comment: What are you expecting vs what are you receiving?

Comment: I would like the array found to output the students who are taking subjects maths or english and have spent 150 minutes on them, at the moment with my code I get the correct students taking maths and english but the total is completely wrong.

Comment: Did you notice that you're defining `index` twice?

Comment: You have some overlap going here with your `index` variable. Also, within your nested loop, you shouldn't have to use `value.time[index].minutes`. The nested loop is already looping through each `time` object, so you should just be able to reference the item & index (once your overlapping `index`es are properly separated).

Comment: please add how the result should look like.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good candidate for using the Javscript [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) functions.

Filter will run a function against each entry in an array, returning a new array with only the values for which that function returned `true`.

Reduce will keep a total value while iterating over each entry in an array. You could say it's used to "reduce" an array into a single value, which is what we want to do here.

Here's an example, given that the `students` variable contains your array of students:

```js
// We'll match against this variable
var desiredSubject = "maths"

// First, we iterate over each student in the array
var time = students.reduce(function(previousTime, student) {
  // Inside the array is another array, so we want to
  // reduce that one after filtering it to match our subject
  var subjectTime = student.time.filter(function(subject) {
    // Keep only subjects that match ours
    return subject.subject == desiredSubject;
  }).reduce(function(previousMinutes, subject) {
    // Then sum up the minutes from each one
    return previousMinutes + subject.minutes;
  }, 0); // Our initial sum is 0
  // Sum up each student's minutes
  return previousTime + subjectTime;
}, 0); // Again, with an initial sum of 0
```

Keep in mind that a common "gotcha" with the `reduce` function is that you have your starting value *after* the reduce function. It's very easy to forget to put it there.

Comment: thank you very much, it looks great, will definitely guide me in the right direction:-)

Comment: I'll add that in Angular for something like this it would be a good practice to put this on a `service` if it's only to be used in code or a `filter` if it's going to be displayed to the user. That way you can reduce the amount of code in your scope and (if it's a filter) the view will update itself if a `$scope.students` array were to change.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
var students = [{"id": 1,"name": "Natalie","gender": "female","time": [{"subject": "geography","minutes": 100}, {"subject": "english","minutes": 20}, {"subject": "maths","minutes": 760}]}, {"id": 2,"name": "John","gender": "male","time": [{"subject": "spanish","minutes": 450}, {"subject": "maths","minutes": 900}, {"subject": "geography","minutes": 200}]}],
    getTotalMinutes = function (time) {
      return time
        .map(function (s) {
          return s.minutes;
        })
        .reduce(function (a, b) {
          return a + b;
        }, 0);
    },
    result = students.map(function (student) {
      return {
        [student.name]: getTotalMinutes(student.time)
      };
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Useer the question is to get the sum of the total time spent??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `students.reduce` to produce a collection of subjects with the sum of the times for each:

```js
var students = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Natalie",
    "gender": "female",
    "time": [{
        "subject": "geography",
        "minutes": 100
    }, {
        "subject": "english",
        "minutes": 20
    }, {
        "subject": "maths",
        "minutes": 760
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John",
    "gender": "male",
    "time": [{
        "subject": "spanish",
        "minutes": 450
    }, {
        "subject": "maths",
        "minutes": 900
    }, {
        "subject": "geography",
        "minutes": 200
    }]
}]

var subjectTimes = students.reduce(function(result, student) {
    student.time.reduce(function(prev, time) {
        if (time.subject in result)
            result[time.subject] += time.minutes;
        else
            result[time.subject] = time.minutes;
    }, {})
    return result;
}, {});

console.log(subjectTimes);
```